# UI-Grid SortChanged not called on expandable grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

UI-Grid: v3.2.1

When attempting to sort a column in an expanded grid I have noticed that the column does not call our `SortChanged` callback.

We are using external sorting in combination with expandable grids.

We set up sorting with the following call

```
controller.gridOptions = {
  data: controller.myData,
  enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
  enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
  useExternalSorting: true,
  expandableRowTemplate: urls.SubGridTemplate,
  enableGridMenu: true,
  rowHeight: gridRowHeight,
  minRowsToShow: minRowsToShow,
  enableFiltering: true,
  useExternalFiltering: true,
  enableSelectionModeToggle: true,
  columnDefs: templates.getGridColumnDefinitions(
    { advancedFilterChanged: advancedFilterChanged },
    controller.gridSettings
  )
};
```

Then

```
angularGridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, sortChanged);
```

We then setup the expandable grid with

```
  angularGridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(
    $scope,
    retrieveDetailRows
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expandable grids do not appear to use the `$scope.core.on.sortChanged($scope, sortChanged)`.

In my case the default sorting algorithms were defaulting to string because of this caveat.

"The sort algorithm is chosen based on the column type. ui-grid will guess the type based on the data, although if you load data asynchronously after the columns it will often decide all your columns are string."
[Sorting Documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20102%20Sorting)

Explicitly setting column type fixed this for me.

```
{
  field: "myDataField",
  displayName: "My Column Header",
  type: "number",
  minWidth: 93,
  maxWidth: 120
}
```

If you need a more complex sort you can set a custom sort on each column.